# Прикрепил домен и не открывается index.php

Tags: хостинг, домен

Теперь при попытке зайти на сайт, изначально не открывается index.php. Хотя если вручную пути прописать, всё открывается. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем дело?

Comment: В.htaccess что прописано?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте что-то эхнуть в самом начале файла index.php и поставить die(); если эхо сработает то до индекса доходит... если нет то проблема в .htaccess. если проходит дебаж построчно и вскрой отображение ошибок...может там ответ есть...плюс проверьте версию пхп...начиная с 5.6 нет потдежки шорттегов - может и в этом быть проблема...

Comment: "начиная с 5.6 нет потдежки шорттегов - может и в этом быть проблема" - чего это вдруг? Директива short_open_tag никуда не делась, она и в PHP 7 есть.